# Automorphisms of projective space

Tags: projective-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space#Generalizations), Aut(P(V)) = PGL(V).  Apparently this is proved by using *sheaves generated by global sections* but I'm not familiar with this notion.  I would appreciate it if anyone could provide a reference where this is proved.

Comment: It's in Hartshorne, 7.1.1: http://books.google.com/books?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&lpg=PA151&ots=XN892EOHsa&dq=Hartshorne%20automorphisms&pg=PA151#v=onepage&q=Hartshorne%20automorphisms&f=false

Comment: The question has been closed: a reference was provided in the comments, which was accepted by the OP.